# Move node along path without PathTransition

Tags: javafx, path

**Problem**

I want to move an object along a Path. The PathTransition works in terms of Duration, but I need to use the movement along the Path in an AnimationTimer.

**Question**

Does anyone know a way to move a Node along a given Path via AnimationTimer?

Or if someone has a better idea of smoothing the rotation of the nodes at the sharp edges along hard waypoints, it would suffice as well.

**Code**

I need it for moving an object along a sharp path, but the rotation should have smooth turns. The code below draws the path along waypoints (black color).

I thought a means of doing this would be to shorten the path segments (red color) and instead of a hard LineTo make a CubicCurveTo (yellow color).

The PathTransition conveniently would move the Node along the path with correct rotation at the edges, but unfortunately it works only on a Duration basis.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Cut a given path.
 * Black = original
 * Red = cut off
 * Yellow = smoothed using bezier curve
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    /**
     * Pixels that are cut off from start and end of the paths in order to shorten them and make the path smoother.
     */
    private double SMOOTHNESS = 30;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1600,900);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        // get waypoints for path
        List<Point2D> waypoints = getWayPoints();

        // draw a path with sharp edges
        // --------------------------------------------
        Path sharpPath = createSharpPath( waypoints);

        sharpPath.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        sharpPath.setStrokeWidth(8);
        sharpPath.setStrokeType(StrokeType.CENTERED);   

        root.getChildren().add( sharpPath);


        // draw a path with shortened edges
        // --------------------------------------------
        Path shortenedPath = createShortenedPath(waypoints, SMOOTHNESS);

        shortenedPath.setStroke(Color.RED);
        shortenedPath.setStrokeWidth(5);
        shortenedPath.setStrokeType(StrokeType.CENTERED);   

        root.getChildren().add( shortenedPath);


        // draw a path with smooth edges
        // --------------------------------------------
        Path smoothPath = createSmoothPath(waypoints, SMOOTHNESS);

        smoothPath.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        smoothPath.setStrokeWidth(2);
        smoothPath.setStrokeType(StrokeType.CENTERED);  

        root.getChildren().add( smoothPath);

        // move arrow on path
        // --------------------------------------------
        ImageView arrow = createArrow(30,30);
        root.getChildren().add( arrow);

        PathTransition pt = new PathTransition( Duration.millis(10000), smoothPath);
        pt.setNode(arrow);
        pt.setAutoReverse(true);
        pt.setCycleCount( Transition.INDEFINITE);
        pt.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pt.play();

    }

    /**
     * Create a path from the waypoints
     * @param waypoints
     * @return
     */
    private Path createSharpPath( List<Point2D> waypoints) {

        Path path = new Path();

        for( Point2D point: waypoints) {
            if( path.getElements().isEmpty()) {
                path.getElements().add(new MoveTo( point.getX(), point.getY()));
            }
            else {
                path.getElements().add(new LineTo( point.getX(), point.getY()));
            }
        }

        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Create a path from the waypoints, shorten the path and create a line segment between segments
     * @param smoothness Pixels that are cut of from start and end.
     * @return
     */
    private Path createShortenedPath( List<Point2D> waypoints, double smoothness) {

        Path path = new Path();

        // waypoints to path
        Point2D prev = null;
        double x;
        double y;

        for( int i=0; i < waypoints.size(); i++) {

            Point2D curr = waypoints.get( i);

            if( i == 0) {

                path.getElements().add(new MoveTo( curr.getX(), curr.getY()));

                x = curr.getX();
                y = curr.getY();

            }
            else {

                // shorten previous path
                double distanceX = curr.getX() - prev.getX();
                double distanceY = curr.getY() - prev.getY();

                double rad = Math.atan2(distanceY,  distanceX);

                double distance = Math.sqrt( distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

                // cut off the paths except the last one
                if( i != waypoints.size() - 1) {
                    distance -= smoothness;
                }

                x = prev.getX() + distance * Math.cos(rad);
                y = prev.getY() + distance * Math.sin(rad);

                path.getElements().add(new LineTo( x, y));

                // shorten current path
                if( i + 1 < waypoints.size()) {

                    Point2D next = waypoints.get( i+1);

                    distanceX = next.getX() - curr.getX();
                    distanceY = next.getY() - curr.getY();

                    distance = smoothness;

                    rad = Math.atan2(distanceY,  distanceX);

                    x = curr.getX() + distance * Math.cos(rad);
                    y = curr.getY() + distance * Math.sin(rad);

                    path.getElements().add(new LineTo( x, y));
                }
            }

            prev = curr;

        }

        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Create a path from the waypoints, shorten the path and create a smoothing cubic curve segment between segments
     * @param smoothness Pixels that are cut of from start and end.
     * @return
     */
    private Path createSmoothPath( List<Point2D> waypoints, double smoothness) {

        Path smoothPath = new Path();
        smoothPath.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        smoothPath.setStrokeWidth(2);
        smoothPath.setStrokeType(StrokeType.CENTERED);  

        // waypoints to path
        Point2D ctrl1;
        Point2D ctrl2;
        Point2D prev = null;
        double x;
        double y;

        for( int i=0; i < waypoints.size(); i++) {

            Point2D curr = waypoints.get( i);

            if( i == 0) {

                smoothPath.getElements().add(new MoveTo( curr.getX(), curr.getY()));

                x = curr.getX();
                y = curr.getY();

            }
            else {

                // shorten previous path
                double distanceX = curr.getX() - prev.getX();
                double distanceY = curr.getY() - prev.getY();

                double rad = Math.atan2(distanceY,  distanceX);

                double distance = Math.sqrt( distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

                // cut off the paths except the last one
                if( i != waypoints.size() - 1) {
                    distance -= smoothness;
                }
                // System.out.println( "Segment " + i + ", angle: " + Math.toDegrees( rad) + ", distance: " + distance);

                x = prev.getX() + distance * Math.cos(rad);
                y = prev.getY() + distance * Math.sin(rad);

                smoothPath.getElements().add(new LineTo( x, y));

                // shorten current path and add a smoothing segment to it
                if( i + 1 < waypoints.size()) {

                    Point2D next = waypoints.get( i+1);

                    distanceX = next.getX() - curr.getX();
                    distanceY = next.getY() - curr.getY();

                    distance = smoothness;

                    rad = Math.atan2(distanceY,  distanceX);

                    x = curr.getX() + distance * Math.cos(rad);
                    y = curr.getY() + distance * Math.sin(rad);

                    ctrl1 = curr;
                    ctrl2 = curr;
                    smoothPath.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(ctrl1.getX(), ctrl1.getY(), ctrl2.getX(), ctrl2.getY(), x, y));
                }
            }

            prev = curr;

        }

        return smoothPath;
    }

    /**
     * Waypoints for the path
     * @return
     */
    public List<Point2D> getWayPoints() {
        List<Point2D> path = new ArrayList<>();

        // rectangle
//      path.add(new Point2D( 100, 100));
//      path.add(new Point2D( 400, 100));
//      path.add(new Point2D( 400, 400));
//      path.add(new Point2D( 100, 400));
//      path.add(new Point2D( 100, 100));


        // rectangle with peak on right
        path.add(new Point2D( 100, 100));
        path.add(new Point2D( 400, 100));
        path.add(new Point2D( 450, 250));
        path.add(new Point2D( 400, 400));
        path.add(new Point2D( 100, 400));
        path.add(new Point2D( 100, 100));

        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Create an arrow as ImageView 
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    private ImageView createArrow( double width, double height) {

        WritableImage wi;

        Polygon arrow = new Polygon( 0, 0, width, height / 2, 0, height); // left/right lines of the arrow

        SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

        wi = new WritableImage( (int) width, (int) height);
        arrow.snapshot(parameters, wi);

        return new ImageView( wi);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PathTransition` has a public `interpolate` method that could be called in any fraction between 0 (start) and 1 (end), but sadly it's not intended for the user, and it can be called only while path transition is running.

If you have a look at how `interpolate` works, it uses an internal class called `Segment`, based on linear segments within the path.

So the first step is converting your original path into a linear one:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;
import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurveTo;

/**
 *
 * @author jpereda
 */
public class LinearPath {

    private final Path originalPath;

    public LinearPath(Path path){
        this.originalPath=path;
    }

    public Path generateLinePath(){
        /*
        Generate a list of points interpolating the original path
        */
        originalPath.getElements().forEach(this::getPoints);

        /*
        Create a path only with MoveTo,LineTo
        */
        Path path = new Path(new MoveTo(list.get(0).getX(),list.get(0).getY()));
        list.stream().skip(1).forEach(p->path.getElements().add(new LineTo(p.getX(),p.getY())));
        path.getElements().add(new ClosePath());
        return path;
    }

    private Point2D p0;
    private List<Point2D> list;
    private final int POINTS_CURVE=5;

    private void getPoints(PathElement elem){
        if(elem instanceof MoveTo){
            list=new ArrayList<>();
            p0=new Point2D(((MoveTo)elem).getX(),((MoveTo)elem).getY());
            list.add(p0);
        } else if(elem instanceof LineTo){
            list.add(new Point2D(((LineTo)elem).getX(),((LineTo)elem).getY()));
        } else if(elem instanceof CubicCurveTo){
            Point2D ini = (list.size()>0?list.get(list.size()-1):p0);
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, POINTS_CURVE).forEach(i->list.add(evalCubicBezier((CubicCurveTo)elem, ini, ((double)i)/POINTS_CURVE)));
        } else if(elem instanceof QuadCurveTo){
            Point2D ini = (list.size()>0?list.get(list.size()-1):p0);
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, POINTS_CURVE).forEach(i->list.add(evalQuadBezier((QuadCurveTo)elem, ini, ((double)i)/POINTS_CURVE)));
        } else if(elem instanceof ClosePath){
            list.add(p0);
        } 
    }

    private Point2D evalCubicBezier(CubicCurveTo c, Point2D ini, double t){
        Point2D p=new Point2D(Math.pow(1-t,3)*ini.getX()+
                3*t*Math.pow(1-t,2)*c.getControlX1()+
                3*(1-t)*t*t*c.getControlX2()+
                Math.pow(t, 3)*c.getX(),
                Math.pow(1-t,3)*ini.getY()+
                3*t*Math.pow(1-t, 2)*c.getControlY1()+
                3*(1-t)*t*t*c.getControlY2()+
                Math.pow(t, 3)*c.getY());
        return p;
    }

    private Point2D evalQuadBezier(QuadCurveTo c, Point2D ini, double t){
        Point2D p=new Point2D(Math.pow(1-t,2)*ini.getX()+
                2*(1-t)*t*c.getControlX()+
                Math.pow(t, 2)*c.getX(),
                Math.pow(1-t,2)*ini.getY()+
                2*(1-t)*t*c.getControlY()+
                Math.pow(t, 2)*c.getY());
        return p;
    }
}
```

Now, based on `PathTransition.Segment` class, and removing all the private or deprecated API, I've come up with this class with a public `interpolator` method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;

/**
 * Based on javafx.animation.PathTransition
 * 
 * @author jpereda
 */
public class PathInterpolator {

    private final Path originalPath;
    private final Node node;

    private double totalLength = 0;
    private static final int SMOOTH_ZONE = 10;
    private final ArrayList<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>();
    private Segment moveToSeg = Segment.getZeroSegment();
    private Segment lastSeg = Segment.getZeroSegment();

    public PathInterpolator(Path path, Node node){
        this.originalPath=path;
        this.node=node;
        calculateSegments();
    }

    private void calculateSegments() {
        segments.clear();
        Path linePath = new LinearPath(originalPath).generateLinePath();
        linePath.getElements().forEach(elem->{
            Segment newSeg = null;
            if(elem instanceof MoveTo){
                moveToSeg = Segment.newMoveTo(((MoveTo)elem).getX(),((MoveTo)elem).getY(), lastSeg.accumLength);
                newSeg = moveToSeg;
            } else if(elem instanceof LineTo){
                newSeg = Segment.newLineTo(lastSeg, ((LineTo)elem).getX(),((LineTo)elem).getY());
            } else if(elem instanceof ClosePath){
                newSeg = Segment.newClosePath(lastSeg, moveToSeg);
                if (newSeg == null) {
                    lastSeg.convertToClosePath(moveToSeg);
                }
            }
            if (newSeg != null) {
                segments.add(newSeg);
                lastSeg = newSeg;
            }
        });
        totalLength = lastSeg.accumLength;
    }

    public void interpolate(double frac) {
        double part = totalLength * Math.min(1, Math.max(0, frac));
        int segIdx = findSegment(0, segments.size() - 1, part);
        Segment seg = segments.get(segIdx);

        double lengthBefore = seg.accumLength - seg.length;

        double partLength = part - lengthBefore;

        double ratio = partLength / seg.length;
        Segment prevSeg = seg.prevSeg;
        double x = prevSeg.toX + (seg.toX - prevSeg.toX) * ratio;
        double y = prevSeg.toY + (seg.toY - prevSeg.toY) * ratio;
        double rotateAngle = seg.rotateAngle;

        // provide smooth rotation on segment bounds
        double z = Math.min(SMOOTH_ZONE, seg.length / 2);
        if (partLength < z && !prevSeg.isMoveTo) {
            //interpolate rotation to previous segment
            rotateAngle = interpolate(
                    prevSeg.rotateAngle, seg.rotateAngle,
                    partLength / z / 2 + 0.5F);
        } else {
            double dist = seg.length - partLength;
            Segment nextSeg = seg.nextSeg;
            if (dist < z && nextSeg != null) {
                //interpolate rotation to next segment
                if (!nextSeg.isMoveTo) {
                    rotateAngle = interpolate(
                            seg.rotateAngle, nextSeg.rotateAngle,
                            (z - dist) / z / 2);
                }
            }
        }
        node.setTranslateX(x - getPivotX());
        node.setTranslateY(y - getPivotY());
        node.setRotate(rotateAngle);
    }

    private double getPivotX() {
        final Bounds bounds = node.getLayoutBounds();
        return bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth()/2;
    }

    private double getPivotY() {
        final Bounds bounds = node.getLayoutBounds();
        return bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight()/2;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the first segment having accumulated length
     * from the path beginning, greater than {@code length}
     */
    private int findSegment(int begin, int end, double length) {
        // check for search termination
        if (begin == end) {
            // find last non-moveTo segment for given length
            return segments.get(begin).isMoveTo && begin > 0
                    ? findSegment(begin - 1, begin - 1, length)
                    : begin;
        }
        // otherwise continue binary search
        int middle = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
        return segments.get(middle).accumLength > length
                ? findSegment(begin, middle, length)
                : findSegment(middle + 1, end, length);
    }
    /** Interpolates angle according to rate,
     *  with correct 0->360 and 360->0 transitions
     */
    private static double interpolate(double fromAngle, double toAngle, double ratio) {
        double delta = toAngle - fromAngle;
        if (Math.abs(delta) > 180) {
            toAngle += delta > 0 ? -360 : 360;
        }
        return normalize(fromAngle + ratio * (toAngle - fromAngle));
    }

    /** Converts angle to range 0-360
     */
    private static double normalize(double angle) {
        while (angle > 360) {
            angle -= 360;
        }
        while (angle < 0) {
            angle += 360;
        }
        return angle;
    }

    private static class Segment {

        private static final Segment zeroSegment = new Segment(true, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        boolean isMoveTo;
        double length;
        // total length from the path's beginning to the end of this segment
        double accumLength;
        // end point of this segment
        double toX;
        double toY;
        // segment's rotation angle in degrees
        double rotateAngle;
        Segment prevSeg;
        Segment nextSeg;

        private Segment(boolean isMoveTo, double toX, double toY,
                double length, double lengthBefore, double rotateAngle) {
            this.isMoveTo = isMoveTo;
            this.toX = toX;
            this.toY = toY;
            this.length = length;
            this.accumLength = lengthBefore + length;
            this.rotateAngle = rotateAngle;
        }

        public static Segment getZeroSegment() {
            return zeroSegment;
        }

        public static Segment newMoveTo(double toX, double toY,
                double accumLength) {
            return new Segment(true, toX, toY, 0, accumLength, 0);
        }

        public static Segment newLineTo(Segment fromSeg, double toX, double toY) {
            double deltaX = toX - fromSeg.toX;
            double deltaY = toY - fromSeg.toY;
            double length = Math.sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));
            if ((length >= 1) || fromSeg.isMoveTo) { // filtering out flattening noise
                double sign = Math.signum(deltaY == 0 ? deltaX : deltaY);
                double angle = (sign * Math.acos(deltaX / length));
                angle = normalize(angle / Math.PI * 180);
                Segment newSeg = new Segment(false, toX, toY,
                        length, fromSeg.accumLength, angle);
                fromSeg.nextSeg = newSeg;
                newSeg.prevSeg = fromSeg;
                return newSeg;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static Segment newClosePath(Segment fromSeg, Segment moveToSeg) {
            Segment newSeg = newLineTo(fromSeg, moveToSeg.toX, moveToSeg.toY);
            if (newSeg != null) {
                newSeg.convertToClosePath(moveToSeg);
            }
            return newSeg;
        }

        public void convertToClosePath(Segment moveToSeg) {
            Segment firstLineToSeg = moveToSeg.nextSeg;
            nextSeg = firstLineToSeg;
            firstLineToSeg.prevSeg = this;
        }

    }

}
```

Basically, once you have a linear path, for every line it generates a `Segment`. Now with the list of these segments you can call the `interpolate` method to calculate the position and rotation of the node at any fraction between 0 and 1.

And finally you can create an `AnimationTimer` in your application:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ...
    // move arrow on path
    // --------------------------------------------
    ImageView arrow = createArrow(30,30);
    root.getChildren().add( arrow);

    PathInterpolator interpolator=new PathInterpolator(smoothPath, arrow);

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            double millis=(now/1_000_000)%10000;
            interpolator.interpolate(millis/10000);
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Note that now you can implement different interpolating functions as long as they go from 0 to 1. Like this one: `interpolator.interpolate(Math.abs(Math.sin(millis/10000*2d*Math.PI)));`

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that, thanks for the hint. That's a nice add-on and very useful, I can use that.