# Animate along path with additional requirements

Tags: java, animation, javafx

For a game I am developing I want to animate an object along a path. There are three sides to this; therefore I am unsure what approach is the best solution.

**The path animation**

Currently the path is made up as a series of points which means I am using [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) with only straight lines. However I intend to change this later on to a [Bézier curve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CubicCurve.html). Currently the points are at a distance between 5 and 8 pixels. I also intend to reduce the number of control points on the curve.
When saying animation I am thinking [PathTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html), but I am not set on this, as based on the various constraints there might be better solutions.

The object that is animated along the path is an `ImageView` but could also be something as simple as a `Shape` (like `Circle`).

**The duration**

The game is driven by a timer. The timer sends `tick` events. How much ingame time has passed for an tick depends on the tick interval: An ingame tick can represent the passing of 5 minutes or one hour. A tick happens every 100 ms.

Based on the tick interval it is possible to determine the initial duration of the animation:

```
int intervalInMinutes = 5;
int ingameAnimationDurationInMinutes = 60 * 24;
int nbTicks = ingameAnimationDurationInMinutes / 5; // = 288
int durationInMs = 100 * nbTicks; // 28800 ms = 28.8s
```

However it is possible that the tick interval changes at any time (e.g. 5 minutes -> 30 minutes). This means that the remaining animation should be sped up by factor 6.
At this point I see the following options:

- Update the duration of the animation. For a `PathTransition` this seems easy, but other approaches (like `KeyFrame` animation) might have an issue here.
- Stop the running animation and reinitialize the animation from the current position. I think this could be difficult as the current location may not match with one of the control points in the curve, which would mean that the curve (or at least the first segment) needs to be recalculated.
- Create the animation iteratively: animate along the curve only for one tick. For this approach the same issues apply as for the one above: When the animation is finished the position of the animated object must be at a control point. If the tick interval changes the segments between the control points change as well.

**External update**

The position of the animated object needs to be updated in it's model so other parts of the code can react to the changed position. I can envision various scenarios here:

- On each tick query the position of the object that is animated and update the position in it's model
- Animation updates the position of the object. For this approach however I would probably need an `KeyFrame` animation or even a `KeyFrame` animation together with an [Interpolator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html).
- Do not use one of the built in animations, but update the position on each tick (as there are only 10 ticks/s this will not result in a smooth animation)

What is a good approach to address these requirements without making the solution too complicated? It is well possible that there are aspects that I have overlooked or even other options that I am unaware of.

Comment: I think the built-in animations work best when you expect them to run to completion with a fixed rate in the vast majority of cases. In other cases, such as the one you describe, using a different solution usually seems to work better. Consider using an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) to handle the "ticks": this will ensure animation as smooth as possible. Have a look at Steven van Impe's blog posts ([part 1](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) and [part 2](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html). (2 is JavaFX).

Comment: Also this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555912/move-node-along-path-without-pathtransition) is pretty useful, as it provides an interpolator method that updates the node and can be used in an `AnimationTimer`. If I return the new location from the interpolate method and handle the UI update in the `AnimationTimer` that should give me more freedom, as there will be many moving object, but only a few need to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch right now to Bezier curves, I think your problem is instantly solved. Bezier curves have a parameter space, usually [0,1], which *somewhat* translates to speed (the argument of a curve is usually named t for time in mathematics for a reason). Therefore, if you have your curve, either as an actual polynom or as some control points that you evaluate by de Casteljau, all you need to know about your progression on the curve is the progression within the parameter space.

Therefore, a tick would be a certain distance within the parameter space, like 1/1000 if 1000 ticks is how many ticks it takes to finish the curve. You'd simply add 1/1000 to the current value of the parameter and evaluate your curve for that one.

If that's not smooth enough for you, then you could do the following: Think of as the next ticks position as where you want to be and do an animation to that from your current position in linear manner. If your ticks subdivide the curve fine enough, nobody will be able to see the linear segments (this should suffice for a game, wouldn't do it for a cutting machine).

Comment: In Javafx a Bèzier curve is represented as a [CubicCurve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CubicCurve.html), which would mean that I have to do the recalculation of the space parameter per tick, if the interval changes, which means recalculation of the curve. How would this approach solve the third issue with updating the external model?

Comment: That class seems to have only a paint method, not a parameter evaluation. I don't know why they did not include one since they probably have it internally for evaluating the points on the curve, but yes, sadly that means you need to recompute it. If you want the coordinates of the object, you might want to use another class. Or write one, Bezier curves are pretty easy to implement.

Comment: When I posted the question it did not occur to me, that what I actually need is a Bèzier path and not only a single curve. This makes the whole thing a bit more complicated especially if I have to compute each segment on my own.